# python cannot find python in rhel8

Tags: rhel, python, python3

> **What specific syntax or configuration must be changed to get a RHEL8 vm to successfully run the simple python programs below?**

**PROBLEM DEFINITION:**

A simple python 3 program uses the subprocess module to call another simple python 3 program.  When run in Windows, the expected output results, but when run in RHEL 8, the following error results:

```
b'/bin/sh: python: command not found\n'
```

**THE TWO SIMPLE PROGRAMS:**

The contents of `command_test.py` are:

```
import subprocess

def runShellCommand(commandToRun):
  proc = subprocess.Popen( commandToRun,cwd=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
  while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if line:
      print(line)
    else:
      break

myCmd = "python call_me.py"
runShellCommand(myCmd)
```

The contents of `call_me.py` are:

```
print("If you see this, then I was called correctly.")
```

**SUCCESSFULL WINDOWS RESULTS:**

When run in Windows, the two simple programs give the expected results as follows:

```
C:\path\to\somedir>python command_test.py
b'If you see this, then I was called correctly.\r\n'
```

**LINUX ERROR RESULTS:**

When run in a RHEL8 virtual machine, the following error output results:

```
[user@someVMSS000001 somedir]$ python command_test.py
b'/bin/sh: python: command not found\n'
```

However, when we call the second program directly from the terminal, the second program runs fine as follows:

```
[user@someVMSS000001 somedir]$ python call_me.py
If you see this, then I was called correctly.
```

And when we check that python is installed from the terminal, we also get confirmation that python is indeed installed and visible as follows:

```
[user@someVMSS000001 somedir]$ python --version
Python 3.8.12
```

**CLOUD-INIT PYTHON INSTALL CODE:**

The following lines from the cloud-init file that provisions the VM define the python configuration which is causing the problem documented above:

```
dnf install python3.8 -y
dnf remove python3.6 -y
rm -rf /usr/bin/python3
mv /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3

python3 --version

dnf install -y python3-setuptools
dnf install python3-pip -y

python3 -m pip install pyyaml
python3 -m pip install requests
python3 -m pip install awscli

#Set alias so python commands use python3
echo "alias python=python3" >> /etc/bashrc

dnf clean all
dnf update python3 -y

python3 --version
```

**So the problem seems to be that python cannot see python when the subprocess module is run in rhel8.**

Comment: How exactly is `python` associated to `python3`? is it perhaps an alias, that is expanded in your interactive shell but not by `/bin/sh`?

Comment: @steeldriver  I just posted the python install/configuration code from the `cloud-init` file to the end of the OP.  Looks like an alias per your theory.  Does the new information at the end of the OP make it easier to answer this question?

Comment: Can it be that the script has Windows line breaks (`\r\n` instead of `\n`)?

Answer (score 3):

In your interactive bash shell, `python` is resolved to `python3` by an alias.

Aliases are not inherited, so the `/bin/sh` sub-process can't resolve it. Although you *could* create a symbolic link so that `python` resolves to `python3` via the shell's inherited `PATH`, best practice is to specify `python3` explicitly.

See this related discussion at [Python in RHEL 8](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/11/14/python-in-rhel-8-3#)

Comment: Please answer the question, which is stated in the OP as **What specific syntax or configuration must be changed to get a RHEL7 vm to successfully run the simple python programs below?**  The answer needs to show how the function inside `command_test.py` can find `python3` when a `python` command is called.

Comment: @CodeMed I think it can inferred from this answer that all you have to do is replace `python` with `python3` in your script. Or, more generally, just use `python3` everywhere going forward.

Comment: @SethMMorton That is not acceptable.  What is more, the objections raised by others here do not apply to RHEL8.  steeldriver completely failed to address this question.  All the downvoters are completely wrong.  Future readers of this thread should completely disregard steeldriver's wrong response which is incorrectly classified as an answer above.